# Using BooleanToVisibilityConverter without MVVM

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I'm using VB.Net & WPF (not using MVVM as I'm not familiar with it)

I have a Toolbar control in my User Control Style whose Visibility needs to be set from code behind so I decided to use BooleanToVisibilityConverter. I have a Boolean variable in my code depending on whose value toolbar visibility needs to be set.

How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Edit

Tried following

**XAML**

```
<Window.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>

<ToolBarTray Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}"/>
```

**VB.Net Code**

```
Dim IsToolbarVisible As Boolean = True

Public Property ToolbarVisibality As Boolean
    Get
        Return IsToolbarVisible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        IsToolbarVisible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

How to Pass value of IsToolBarVisisble to Boolean TO Visibility Converter ???

Comment: This totally unrelated to MVVM or the absence thereof, MVVM is a rather high-level pattern. What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: added sample short code in edit section as cannot write whole code

Answer (score 0):

Right now your binding uses the `DataContext` as value. You'll want to set the `DataContext` to the object holding a public `IsToolbarVisible` property (is that a property? looks like a field, i don't speak vb) and set the `Binding.Path` to `IsToolbarVisible`. Read the [data binding overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Added Public Property, now what

Comment: I explained what you need to do, if you don't understand it read the overview.

Comment: I Tried 
`code` TB1.Visibility = New Binding With {.Source = IsToolbarVisible, .Converter = New BooleanToVisibilityConverter} `code` got error Value of Type Binding Cannot Be Converted to Visibility

Comment: You just need to modify the binding in XAML, why would you try to do that in code?

Comment: `{Binding Path=IsToolbarVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibility}}`, just set the `DataContext` accordingly. Also, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Never used INotifyPropertyChanged & DataContext. I'm new with XAML so please understand

Comment: That's exactly why i said you should **read the bloody overview**.

Comment: I read it and got more confused and vb code i put in comment was result of it only

Comment: If you don't understand the basics of data binding, then that's what you should learn first, using converters effectively requires you to be able to construct valid bindings first.